# How to get Page Public Content Access for analysis project?

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api, data-analysis

I'm an undergrad CS student in India and I've started a research internship recently. The project I'll be working on is about studying the impact of digital marketing. For which I need data from a public page(posts, reactions, shares, comments and images if there are any) and for that, I think I need Page Public Content Access. I checked how to get it but I don't have a working app that I can show as I only need data to analyze it.

Can anyone please help me with the process to apply for Public Content Acess permission under such circumstances?

Is there any other way other than Graph-API to get the data that I require?

Comment: Yes you have to use Graph API. Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. Did you read the documentation for "Page Public Content Access"?

Comment: @WizKid yes I did read. But I quite didn't grasp what I need to do to get the access. Cause I don't have a working app. I don't have a way to verify my business(cause I don't have any). I'm sorry if this sounds dumb, I'm still new to Graph API. I don't even require who commented on the post. Just the text. Can you help?

Comment: Business verification is required as you said. So if you don't have a business then you can't get it.